# TV mount is 16.5" wide but stud centers are 17" apart. Is it still safe to mount?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, drywall-anchor, television

I am not able to install the mount by positioning it on the exact center of the studs. Is it alright if the holes are slightly off-center on the studs? The mount I am installing is [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00VMJEK2C), and my TV is 70 lbs.

Would it help if I used Snaptoggles? I was thinking of drilling through the wall and the stud and using the Snaptoggle like that.

Comment: Another option is to screw in diagonally sideways - half an inch sideways isn't much compared to 3-4" screws screws, which you're hopefully using.

Comment: Also, 70lb on a 16" wide bracket sounds kind of high... are you sure this bracket is rated properly?

Comment: That's only 1/4" away from the center of each 1 1/2" wide stud. Not a big deal.

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Yes, it is rated to hold up to 132 lbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last time I encountered that, I put two 2x4's across the stud span, chamfered the edges too a 45 angle and painted it to match the wall. Mounted the bracket onto that, if it's a rental or you just don't want to wreck the walls, put a thin piece of cardboard between the 2x4 and wall before you mount it to make sure it doesn't pull up any paint when you remove it. You might be able to get away with one on stud one with anchor, but if it fails......

Comment: Yeah this seems to be what most people are doing. I guess this way you know for sure that it will hold the weight. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah. A similar thing can also be done with a rectangular piece of 3/4" plywood mounted across several studs. Plywood does a wonderful job of holding screws for the wall mount bracket and it does not project out from the wall as much.

Comment: A good solution, aka a “french cleat.”

Answer (score 2):

As Dan G pointed out, being off-ctr by 0.64 cm on each stud really doesn't matter.
Personally :-) , if I had to deal w/ a similar situation but a worse mismatch, e.g. 14-inch vs 17-inch spacing, I'd do one of 2 things.

1) bolt short lengths of 2x4 vertically to the existing studs, then hang the bracket on these add-ons.

2) (more work and less stable)  get a couple steel plates maybe 6 inches high and wide enough to bolt the bracket onto and also bolt them onto the existing studs.

[image]